# How to remember the last called JavaScript function in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. There is a dropdownlist with two values in it : 2014 and 2015. I also have an HTML table with 12 td elements and I am calling JavaScript functions on each td element onclick event.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" onchange="GetSelectedItem();">
</asp:DropDownList>

<table class="window_month" style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
    <tr id="NavMonth">
        <td id="m1" runat="server" onclick="createChart_Jan();">
         Jan
        </td>
        <td id="m2" runat="server" onclick="createChart_Feb();">
         Feb
        </td>
        <td id="m3" runat="server" onclick="createChart_Mar();">
         Mar
        </td>
         ...
        <td id="m12" runat="server" onclick="createChart_Dec();">
           Dec
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now suppose the user clicked on td with id "m6" and selects year 2015, createChartJune() function will be called and it will display some values in my charts.

Now if user changes the value in the dropdown list from 2015 to 2014, I want to call the last called function ("createChartJune()") again without doing postback.

How do I make the  last called function remembered?

Comment: One possible solution is to save the last-called function to a variable (within a parent scope) whenever the function is invoked. You would need to do this with each of the applicable functions. Then, when you handle the dropdown event, use that variable to call the function.

Comment: The code you have showed us shouldn't be doing a postback when you change items in the dropdown.  Do you have `AutoPostBack=true` in your actual code?

Comment: Listen for the _change_ event in your `drop_down` and create the necessary function that validates, calls some method asynchronously (ajax), and render the result.

Comment: No. There is no autopostback=true in my code and I do not need to do postback. I just need to have the last called function remembered so that I can call it again when the dropdown index is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to remember your function the best way to to that,
is to save it in a var when you call it.

You could give it an index or 
save the string and if it is not empty when you recall the function 
you can call your function.